# AV in IDE when opening any project or creating new in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

After many years of trouble-free use, Delphi 7 is now throwing an Access violation at address 
40233A3E in module 'vclx70.bpl'. Read of address 0000021C.

When starting the IDE, the default empty project and unit/form appear and compile and run fine.

I'm developing Windows apps, running on Windows 7 (x64).

I haven't installed any new packages or tools in many, many months.

I stopped, dead in the water, unable to work.

Any suggestions other than a complete rip and re-install (which takes many hours...)

EDIT:  I un-installed and re-installed Delphi 7.  Now I'm getting Access violation in vcl70.bpl.  I would have thought that uninstalling D7 would completely remove all of its libraries, etc...  Are there folders that I should manually delete after uninstalling D7?

Comment: What did you recently change on that machine?

Comment: Delete the entire registry branch under HKLM\Software\Borland\Delphi and HKCU\Software\Borland\Delphi (if D7 is the only version installed - if you have more than that, just delete the 7.0 branch). This is sounding more and more like a 3rd party component issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem fixed (and major machine rebuild averted)!

Gerrit Beuze of [ModelMaker Tools](http://www.modelmakertools.com) suggested elsewhere:

> Remove all .dsk (project desktop) files for the project you try to load,
>  Temp remove all *.dst (desktop files) from C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin

After performing these steps, the problem appears to have been fixed.

Comment: Excellent! You should accept this answer so it's clear it's solved. I forgot about the issue with .dsk files and Delphi versions < 2006. +1

Answer (score 2):

A read at that low a memory address is typically a problem in a third-party component. However, you say you haven't installed anything new in months.

The other thing that's strange is that you're getting the error in vclx70, which is one of the `CLX` libraries. Are you doing anything using the `CLX` (leftover cross platform - Kylix) forms or dialogs?

If not, you might do a search in your source for `QDialogs`, `QForms`, or any of the other units in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Borland\Delphi7\Source\Clx`, and see if something mistakenly was added that you didn't intend that's pulling `CLX` into your project. If so, change it to the `VCL` version instead (by just removing the 'Q' from the front of the unit name in your source).

EDIT: You might try going into the registry (D7 would be `HKCU\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0`) and temporarily changing the name of the delphiCLXide entry in `Known IDE Packages` to something else (put an underscore in front of the name or something). Then start the IDE. You should get an error message about Delphi being unable to load the package, and asking if you want to try and load it again in the future. Answer 'Yes', and let the IDE continue to load. Then try again with your project and see what happens.

The step above removes CLX temporarily from loading in the IDE designer. (Don't worry, you can just rename the key again to put it back if it's not the problem. If it doesn't come back, make sure the IDE didn't add an entry in the `Disabled Packages` entry; if it did, just remove it.)

If this works, you can open the project options (.DOF) file for your project, and remove the CLX libraries from the `Packages` list. This prevents it from being included when your project is loaded. 
Once you've established whether the problem actually

Comment: Thanks, Ken, for the suggestion.  Nope, I've never touched the CLX stuff. This problem occurs even when I try to create a new project from scratch (File, New, Application...)

Comment: try removing all packages leaving only vcl70.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use XP Mode or another VM infrastructure to run such an old Delphi version on Windows 7 (I do it that way).

Another potential method is to use the compatibility settings in Windows 7 to set it to XP and to exempt the Delphi 7 process from DEP (data execution prevention) policies the system may otherwise impose. I've had some trouble with enabled DEP with older Borland IDEs and also VS 2003.

Comment: I guess I didn't spell my platform out clearly. I've been running fine on this machine running Windows 7 (x64) for years.

Comment: @Robert Frank: but we're talking about a very old program. Using XP mode of the compatibility shims and making sure DEP is turned off at least for the Delphi IDE are still relevant. In fact I got bitten by the latter after I had installed some software that changed the default DEP policy to enforce, where it should have been opt-out in my configuration. Of course it could still be something different. But the DLL placement bug last year has also caused some stir that would affect compatibility with older programs.